# Sum of Random Variables Jointly Gaussian

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution, density-function

Let $X_1$, ..., $X_n$ be random variables and define

$Y_k = \sum_{i=1}^k X_i $, $\hspace{5mm} k= 1, ...,n$

Suppose that $Y_1, ...,Y_n$ are jointly Gaussian. Are $X_1, ..., X_n$ jointly Gaussian?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it will help to see the following:
$$
X_1 = Y_1\\
X_2 = Y_2 - Y_1\\
X_3 = Y_3 - Y_2 \\
\vdots \\
X_n = Y_n - Y_{n-1}
$$
Hence
$$
{\bf X} =
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & -1 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & -1 & 1
\end{pmatrix} 
{\bf Y}
$$
where ${\bf X} = (X_1, ..., X_n)^{T}$ and ${\bf Y} = (Y_1, ..., Y_n)^{T}$.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't thought about this problem that way. I will try writing out a few joint pdfs for X1, X2, etc... as a function of Y1, Y2, etc..., but I don't understand how the matrix will be helpful. Is there a way to do this using matrices?

Comment: Well, I'd suggest instead looking into whether or not the linear transform of a gaussian random vector is again a gaussian random vector...