# If moving average is Gaussian, so are the innovations

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, time-series

Let
$$
X(k) = \sum_{j = 0}^\infty a_j\, \varepsilon(k - j) , \quad k \in \mathbb{N},
$$
where $\sum_{j = 0}^\infty a_j^2 < \infty$ and $\big(\varepsilon(j) \big)_{j \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is a sequence of **uncorrelated** random variables with common mean zero and common finite variance $\sigma > 0$.

If $(X(1), \ldots, X(n))$ are jointly Gaussian for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, is $\big(\varepsilon(j) \big)_{j \in \mathbb{Z}}$ a sequence of Gaussian random variables?

### Related question

This question is a bit related to [this math SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1992176/sum-of-random-variables-jointly-gaussian) but there the proof relied on the invertability of $X$. It is not clear, if this is possible here.

Answer (score -1):

Hi: If you watch the video below, you will see what your $a_j$ are. From that, you can infer that you have the AR(1) below:

$X(k) = \theta \times X(k-1) + \epsilon_k$

where $X(k)$ is Gaussian.

Then, since you have an AR(1) where the response is Gaussian ( jointly Gaussian $X(k)$ implies marginally Gaussian), this implies that the $\epsilon_k$ term has to be Gaussian. Note that, When watching, disregard the constant term since you don't have one. Also, assume that the person in the video goes all the way out to $t = \infty$ rather than stopping at a finite $t$.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mBYgDY7BkBc

Comment: This solution would assume that $a_j = \phi^j$ for some $\vert \phi \vert < 1$ wouldn't it?. That's a restriction because not much about the sequence $a_j$ beside its square-sumability is known. But I may be wrong. Is there a way to argue that the $a_j$ are of the desired form?

Comment: yes, that is correct. Without making that assumption, ( that $a_j = \phi^{j}$ ), I don't know of a way to convert it to an AR(1). It may be possible ( to just take the $a_j$ sequence itself ) and convert to an AR(1) but I don't know how to do that.  Hopefully someone who does will chime in ?